# Formation of ammonia from air and moisture

Tags: biochemistry

On extended bicycle trips I sometimes slept under a plastic sheet, which helped with mosquitoes on hot nights. But there was a noticeable build-up of ammonia which made this almost impossible for more than an hour or so at a time.

Air is mostly nitrogen $(N_2)$ and there is always water (containing hydrogen) on a humid day. But I wonder about the mechanism for the formation of ammonia under these circumstances? There are (according to Wiki) trace amounts of methane and $H_2$ in the air. But methane and hydrogen (g) are I think pretty stable.

I wonder if the presence of exhaled air (containing $CO_2)$ could be a factor?

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're absolutely sure it's Ammonia ($NH_3$) you're smelling, it's probably from *you*.

Ammonia will not spontaneously form at any significant rate from the air. Molecular Nitrogen ($N_2$) is **extremely** stable.

What *can* happen is that during marathon-type activities, muscles turn from carbohydrates (which are later converted into glucose and enter into the Krebs Cycle) as an energy source to proteins themselves.

One of the [waste products of protein catabolism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metabolic_waste) is Ammonia, which is excreted in your sweat if the body can't convert it into Urea ($CH_4N_2O$) quickly enough:

> Ammonia forms with the oxidation of amino groups (-NH<sub>2</sub>), which are removed from the proteins when they convert into carbohydrates. It is a very toxic substance and only one nitrogen atom is removed with it. A lot of water is needed for the ammonia excretion.

Comment: Yes, no mistake about the ammonia. This makes perfect sense. Long distance cycling with little to eat, intense humidity and heat. Thanks.